# pics not loading in codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter, web

I am new to codeigniter and trying to make a controller and a view. The controller has been successfully made and is calling the view. The view is also being called successfully but images are not showing. I have tried putting pics in the same folder as the views and in other folder but none worked.

View

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <!--<link href="/assists/css/font-awsome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->
    <!--<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/assists/css/stylecinemax.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
    <!-- Start CSS Slideshow HEAD section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- End CSS Slider HEAD section -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>

            <div class="header">
                <a class="cinestar" href="#"></a>
                <a id="membersarealink" style="margin-left: 5%" href="#" class="toplink">Home</a>
                <a id="corporatelink" href="#" class="toplink">Corporate</a>
                <div class="imaxbox">
                        <div class="sponsor"><img src="pics/sponsorlogo.png" height="32"></div>
                    </div>
                    <a id="gallerycinestar" href="#" class="toplink">Gallery</a>
                    <a id="aboutus" href="#" class="toplink">About</a>
                    <a id="contactuscinestar" href="#" class="toplink">Contact</a>
                    <div class="contactinfo">
                        <h1>(042) 111 cinema</h1>
                        <a href="#" class="socialicon"><img src="googleplus-header.png" width="24"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="socialicon" target="_blank"><img src="../pics/2.png" width="24"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="socialicon" target="_blank"><img src="../pics/imax-logo.png" width="24"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="topticker" style="background-color:gainsboro">
                        <span>
                            <a class="online-booking-dialogue" href="login.php">Login</a>
                            <a class="members-area-dialogue" href="registration.php" target="_blank">MEMBER REGISTRATION</a>
                        </span>
                        <p style="padding-left: 2%">
                            To get SMS Alerts of our daily schedule and promotions, please dial 111 CINEMA from your cellphone 
                        </p>
                    </div>  <!--toptickter-->        
            </div> <!--header-->
        </body>
        </html>
```

Controller

```
<?php
class front_page extends CI_Controller{
    public function one()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
    }
}
```

this is the output:

[image: output]

Comment: Have you set the base url in config.php you need to.

Answer (score 3):

I can understand it may be confusing for a first-timer but the view-related files like images, css, .etc. should go in the base directory e.g. the same directory where your main Codeigntier index.php file is.

[image]

I like to put my resources in a folder called `assets` and have a subfolder `images`, `css`, `js`, `plugins` .etc.

Then to access them you just have to do something like:

```
<img src="/assets/images/emojis/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

OR

having loaded `$this->load->helper('url');` in your controller (or autoload file):

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/images/emojis/smiley.gif'); ?>" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

Comment: You could take this one step further and use the [`img()` helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html?highlight=helper#img).

Comment: You are right. Although I personally find it a bit verbose if you want to add attributes - at that point you might as well just write it out.

Answer (score 1):

Create an images folder at the same level of the applications folder.

With base_url() you can get the location of your site's base.
For example:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/image.png" alt="image" >
```

Or,

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url("/images/image.png"); ?>" alt="image" >
```